# is there any possibly way to download the Excel Object as Stream not to a Physical path using C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have Created an excel Object now I need to Download the Excel object as stream as excel file  with out creating the Excel file to physical location to disk . Please help me on this

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to download an excel file over HTTP and load it into an Excel.Application instance without saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to save the file to disk in order to have Excel open it.

Use [Path.GetTempFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if you do not want to create a permanent file on disk.